# DirectX 11, exception thrown when updating constant buffer with UpdateSubresource

Tags: buffer, directx-11

So I am very new to DirectX and are trying to learn the basics but I'm running into some problem with my constant buffer. I'm trying to send a struct with three matrices to the vertex shader, but when I try to update the buffer with UpdateSubresource I get "Exception is thrown at 0x710B5DF3 (d3d11.dll) in Demo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000003C".

My struct:

```
struct Matracies
{
   DirectX::XMMATRIX projection;
   DirectX::XMMATRIX world;
   DirectX::XMMATRIX view;
};
Matracies matracies;
```

Buffer creation:

```
ID3D11Buffer*  ConstantBuffer = nullptr;
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC Buffer;
memset(&Buffer, 0, sizeof(Buffer));

Buffer.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
Buffer.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
Buffer.ByteWidth = sizeof(Matracies);
Buffer.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA data;
data.pSysMem = &matracies;
data.SysMemPitch = 0;
data.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

Device->CreateBuffer(&Buffer, &data, &ConstantBuffer);
DeviceContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &ConstantBuffer);
```

Updating buffer:

```
DeviceContext->UpdateSubresource(ConstantBuffer, 0, 0, &matracies, 0, 0);
```

I am not sure what information is relevant to solve this so let me know if anything is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the wooly world of DirectX!

The first two steps in debugging any DirectX program are:

(1) Enable the Debug device. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/). This will generate additional debug output at runtime which gives hints about problems like the one you have above.

(2) If a function returns an `HRESULT`, you must check that for success or failure at runtime. If it was safe to ignore the return value, it would return `void`. See [this page](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed).

If you had done either or both of the above, you would have caught the error returned from `CreateBuffer` above which resulted in `ConstantBuffer` still being a nullptr when you called `UpdateSubresource`.

The reason it failed is that you can't *in general* create a constant buffer that is both `D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT` and `D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE`. DEFAULT usage memory is often in video memory that is not accessible to the CPU. Since you are using `UpdateSubresource` as opposed to `Map`, you should just use:

```
Buffer.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
```

> You should take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) and it's associated tutorials.